# Cant get rid of warning "./~/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js" on react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I got this warning already few days and i cant get rid of it:

Warning in ./~/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js
Critical dependencies:
1:476-483 This seems to be a pre-built javascript file. Though this is possible, it's not recommended. Try to require the original source to get better results.
 @ ./~/ajv/dist/ajv.bundle.js 1:476-483

Comment: Something in your code must be loading that module. Are you importing `ajv` somewhere?

Comment: I am not importing ajv..

Comment: I'd recommend trimming down your application code or webpack config until you stop getting the error. Something is causing it to be loaded, but it's impossible to say with the info we have.

Comment: I have this same problem. I think it has something to do with me importing the 'request' library in my React component.

Comment: You may not be directly importing it, but it is probably a dependency. Try `npm ls ajv` to find out which of your direct dependencies use it.